# Should i put a limit when searching for unique indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example i have this query

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '5123'
```

In this query it will search for all results which have the id of 5123.
But i only want 1 row returned, so i could add LIMIT 1 to the query.

But lets say that `id` is an unique index, will it still continue to search for results after it found one then?

Comment: usually your id is a primary key and then automatically an unique id. no need for limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

One of the things indexes do is precisely what you suggest:

> MySQL uses indexes for these operations:
>
> - To find the rows matching a WHERE clause quickly.
> - To eliminate rows from consideration. If there is a choice between multiple indexes, MySQL normally uses the index that finds the smallest number of rows (the most selective index).

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

More clauses you have in your query more burden it puts on your server, If it has a Unique Constraint defined on this column then there isnt a chance of duplicates in this column so I would personally avoid using LIMIT.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.

That depends on the execution plan.

If there are only a handful rows in the table then the optimizer may decide to do a full table scan. But don't worry, it will never return more than one row if the ID column is unique.

You should NOT add LIMIT 1 to your query. Unless you can see that the query is very slow you should trust the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is defined to be a primary key, then I would not use a `limit` clause.

If `id` merely has a unique index, then I would be inclined to keep the `limit` clause, to be certain that the code does not generate an error.

Somehow, I feel differently about primary keys versus columns that *just* have a unique index.  And, because code can break if extra rows are returned, I would be inclined to be cautious.

By the way, there are cases where such a query could use a unique index and still return multiple rows.  This could happen if the column contained strings and the collations for the column and the database were different.

In terms of performance, the use of `limit` should not make a difference.